# Crm 2016 Create option set indicates all entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-365

I have created an entity, and i want a option for show all entities in create form, how can i do this?
Something like option set in process form:

[image]

Comment: How is this related to programming? https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You can either create a static option set containing all the entities, or you can create a custom web resource with an option set that dynamically populates onLoad, then after the user selects an option store the entity name on a field on the form. The second option is typically what I do.

Comment: @ArunVinoth - done. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's some JavaScript code to retrieve all Entities

Here are some key points about the code

- Using Underscore (`_`) which is available on the `top` frame, but may not be available in other contexts
- Only selecting (`$select`) the `EntityTypeCode` and `DisplayName` properties
- Applying a range of filters to try to reduce the number of results. Filters include the following

  - Must **not** be a Business Process Flow entity
  - Must **not** be an Intersect entity (i.e. the join table in an N:N relationship)
  - Must **not** be an Activity
  - Must **not** be an ActivityParty
  - **Must** be available in Advanced Find
  - **Must** be able to trigger workflow

Code:

```
var underscore = top["_"];
var entityMetadata = (function(_) {

    return { retrieve: queryMetadata };

    function buildEntityList(data)
    {
        var entities = _.chain(data.entities)
            .map(function(entity) { 
                return { 
                    "Name": entity.DisplayName.UserLocalizedLabel.Label, 
                    "ETC": entity.ObjectTypeCode 
                }; 
            })
            .sortBy("Name")
            .value();

        return entities;
    }

    function queryMetadata()
    {
        var select = "$select=DisplayName,ObjectTypeCode";

        var filter = "$filter="
        filter += "IsBPFEntity eq false";
        filter += " and IsIntersect eq false";
        filter += " and IsActivity eq false";
        filter += " and IsActivityParty eq false";
        filter += " and CanTriggerWorkflow eq true";
        filter += " and IsValidForAdvancedFind eq true";

        var p = Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("EntityDefinitions", "?" + select + "&" + filter).then(buildEntityList);
        return p;
    }

})(underscore);
```

This code returns a `promise` with all Entities matching the above criteria. Here's how to call it, and write the results to the browser console:

```
entityMetadata.retrieve().then(console.log);
```

This outputs all the Display Names and Entity Type Codes to the console like so:

[image]

Other answers on StackOverflow show how to build a `select` control with `options` so I won't include that here.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a static option set containing all the entities, or you can create a custom web resource with an option set that dynamically populates onLoad, then after the user selects an option store the entity name on a field on the form. The second option is typically what I do.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the metadata using the WebApi. From there you can retrieve a list of entities and every fields they contain.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607522.aspx